# JS/TS Filter On AsyncIterable<T>

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, asynchronous

I have a variable of type AsyncIterable.  I want to filter on it, for example (psuedo code below) -

```
class SomeClass {
    private SOME_CONST= "ABCDE";

    private async someFunction(): Promise<string> {
        const items: AsyncIterable<string> = await someLibrary.getAsyncItems(); // this library's function returns type of AsyncIterable<T>

        return items.filter(item => item === this.SOME_CONST);
    }
}
```

How can I filter on AsyncIterable?  I get the error - "Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'AsyncIterable'

Comment: filter needs to be on arrays so you either cast your items as so or you use a typeguard to verify the response you get back. Also, what is the structure of `AsyncIterable`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator#examples

Answer (score 1):

You can't filter on a synchronous iterator either, you'll need to it convert it to an array.

At the moment there is no method like `Array.from()` for `AsyncIterable` ([pending proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-from-async)) but you can do following :

```
async function toArray<T>(asyncIterator: AsyncIterable<T>) {
  const arr = [];
  for await (const i of asyncIterator) arr.push(i);
  return arr;
}
```

then you can do

```
declare const items: AsyncIterable<string>;

async function foo() {
  (await toArray(items)).filter(() => true)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=2#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gSwyAtmgFzwCCaAnimAJJ4xQBGEIAPJjNigOYB8A3AFgAUCKiVq8AGYBXahmyp4GJKRgMKrACq8AFOKq16UFTBLlDdEA2ZsdASngBvEfESpM8WDHgBeeADaALpCwm5SSD5QAO5QuPC6yOhY2PBIUl4SRtYmkY7eAHQADjJoABa62PahbnAYMjAoXuqhAL4iYlnScmAKShFIuo4uYQkxcVgqahqVeIT29gVS2BD0ukN%20vMowMiD2Iq1AA)

Answer (score 0):

Just create another `AsyncIterator` that wraps original one using generator function.

I made a example for TypeScript:

```
export function filterAsyncIterator<T>(origin: AsyncIterableIterator<T>, predicate: (element: T) => boolean): AsyncIterableIterator<T> {
    return (async function* () {
        for await (const each of origin) {
            if(predicate(each)){
                yield each;
            }
        }
    })();
}
```

---

`AsyncIterator` is not an actual type. It is an interface that objects can comply by owning a function with named as `[Symbol.asyncIterator]`.

Comment: Why the pointless IIFE? Just write `export async function* filterAsyncIterator<T>(…): AsyncIterableIterator<T> { … }`

Answer (score 0):

Spelling out the direct approach:

```
export async function* filterAsyncIterable<T>(
    iterable: AsyncIterable<T>,
    predicate: (t: T) => boolean,
): AsyncIterable<T> {
    for await (const item of iterable) {
        if (predicate(item)) yield item;
    }
}
```

Similarly, you can write `mapAsyncIterable`, etc. and you will also probably need other helpers like `asyncIterableToArray` and `asyncIterableFirst` (to get the first element).

Then, your code becomes:

```
class SomeClass {
    private SOME_CONST= "ABCDE";

    private async someFunction(): AsyncIterable<string> {
        return filterAsyncIterable(
            someLibrary.getAsyncItems(), 
            item => item === this.SOME_CONST,
        );
    }
}
```

or possibly:

```
class SomeClass {
    private SOME_CONST= "ABCDE";

    private async someFunction(): Promise<string[]> {
        return asyncIterableToArray(filterAsyncIterable(
            someLibrary.getAsyncItems(), 
            item => item === this.SOME_CONST,
        ));
    }
}
```